# SQLSERVERDIALECT for Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, dialect

What is the difference between org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect and org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect . I am trying to debug an application which was not able to read a sequence from DB changing the dialect worked . is org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect deprecated ?